# How to split a file having multiple xml using Node js

Tags: node.js, xml, express, split, stream

I'm learning node-js and I was trying to achieve the problem mentioned below. I have tried to use [xml-splitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-splitter) as well as [xml-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-stream) npm module available in node.js but the error occurs as `Error: Text data outside of root node.`

I have a file as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Party tonight!</body>
</note>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
  <to>Jone</to>
  <from>Dove</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>One batch, Two batch</body>
</note>
```

I want to split the file into two as shown

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Party tonight!</body>
</note>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
  <to>Jone</to>
  <from>Dove</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>One batch, Two batch</body>
</note>
```

Comment: The initial file is not a valid XML file, but contains two concatenated XML files. That's why the XML NPM modules won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a complete working code solving your problem. The main idea is to use 'byline' NPM module to read the file line by line, and to detect when a "new" XML subfile starts.

```
const byline = require("byline");
const fs = require("fs");
const filePath = "./file.xml";

var stream = byline(fs.createReadStream(filePath));
var fileContents = {};
var indexSubFile = 0;
var subFileName;

stream.on("data", function(line) {
    line = line.toString(); // Convert the buffer stream to a string line
    if (/^<\?xml/.test(line)) {
        // New XML sub-file
        indexSubFile++;
        subFileName = "file" + indexSubFile + ".xml";
        fileContents[subFileName] = [line];
    } else {
        fileContents[subFileName].push(line);
    }
});
stream.on("error", function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
stream.on("end", function() {
    var key;

    for (key in fileContents) {
        fs.writeFileSync(key, fileContents[key].join("\n"));
    }
    console.log("Done");
});
```